# How to obtain openstreet API key for nominatim (r)?

Tags: r, api, nominatim

I wanted to use r package [nominatim](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/nominatim) for my program written in R.
I tried to run very simple example `osm_search('Cracow University of Economics')`, however I got the following error:

> Please provide a openstreet API key

I even made an account at https://www.openstreetmap.org/, however it still does not work after specifying the `email` parameter in the `osm_search`- I entered the email that I used during registration at OSM.

How do I obtain the right API key to use with nominatim package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [comments of the source code](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/nominatim/blob/master/R/search.r#L125) you linked there is an explanation:

> @param key To access the openstreetmap API you need a valid API key. You can get it for free at https://developer.mapquest.com

For more info also see https://github.com/hrbrmstr/nominatim/issues/5

Comment: I tought that nominatim allows the user to use OSM API instead of Mapquest one? Correct me if wrong please. I don't want to use the Mapquest one.

Comment: Nominatim has a usage policy which allows some requests for creative and unexpected uses. The R package `nominatim` uses the MapQuest Nominatim API. The Readme of [nominatim](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/nominatim) lists all information regarding the used API, usage policies and lists in the TODO the point "Enable switching Nominatim API server providers".